# PHP not writing all keys to array from MySQL Query

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm having an odd time writing all of the field names as keys to an array from a MySQL Query in PHP. All of the values are making it from the query to the array, but not all of the keys. I'm encoding the response in JSON and sending it to an Android client.

The following is a raw output of one of the `JSON Objects`, contained within a `JSON Array`. As you can see, many of the keys are just numbers. The order of the numbers doesn't line up with the original query either.

```
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):   {
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "STATE": "1",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "RECEIVER_ID": "29",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "LAST_MODIFIED": "2013-08-17     06:15:01",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "CREATED": "2013-08-07     15:51:25",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "UNIQUE_ID": "cef3fc71-073e-11e3-8ffd-0800200c9a66",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "3": "2",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "2": "29",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "1": "918fa7f5-073c-11e3-8ffd-    0800200c9a66",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "0": "2",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "7": "2013-08-07 15:51:25",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "6": "2013-08-17 06:15:01",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "DATA_RECORD_UUID": "918fa7f5-073c-11e3-8ffd-0800200c9a66",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "5": "cef3fc71-073e-11e3-8ffd-0800200c9a66",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "4": "1",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "ID": "2",
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):    "IS_TEST": "2"
08-18 05:41:49.130: I/GETJSON=ACCESSOR(JSON)(20407):   },
```

I've been creating an array of records with this function:

```
    public function getRowArray($mysql_query_result){
    $result=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query_result)){
        $result[]=$row;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And the query result comes from this block, with variables which are pre-escaped with mysql_real_escape_string:

```
$ary=mysql_query("SELECT tRelations.ID,tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID,tRelations.RECEIVER_ID,
    tRelations.IS_TEST,tRelations.STATE,tRelations.UNIQUE_ID,tRelations.LAST_MODIFIED,
    tRelations.CREATED FROM tRelations 
            JOIN tUserData ON (tUserData.UNIQUE_ID=tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID) 
            JOIN tUsers ON (tUsers.ID=tUserData.USER_ID) 
        WHERE tUsers.ID=$user_id AND tRelations.last_modified>'$last_sync' 
        ORDER BY tRelations.ID ASC;") or die(mysql_error());


    if(mysql_num_rows($ary)>0){
        $array2= $this->getRowArray($ary);
```

Might anybody know why the keys are out of order and not all being written? Alternatively, does anybody else favour other methods of converting a MySQL result into a JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

The order of columns is dictated by the order of the select query.

```
SELECT tRelations.ID,tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID,tRelations.RECEIVER_ID,
    tRelations.IS_TEST,tRelations.STATE,tRelations.UNIQUE_ID,tRelations.LAST_MODIFIED,
    tRelations.CREATED FROM tRelations
```

It says: ID, DATA_RECORD_UUID, RECEIVER_ID, IS_TEST, STATE, UNIQUE_ID and it will be also added in that way to the array. You can reorder it to

```
SELECT tRelations.STATE,tRelations.RECEIVER_ID,tRelations.LAST_MODIFIED,
    tRelations.CREATED,tRelations.UNIQUE_ID,tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID,tRelations.ID,
    tRelations.IS_TEST FROM tRelations
```

But it will be hard to get the other fields in that order. You you'll probably have to fill them yourself unless you can use aliases like `tRelation.SOME_FIELD as '2'`.

```
public function getRowArray($mysql_query_result){
    $order=array("STATE", "RECEIVER_ID", "LAST_MODIFIED", "CREATED", "UNIQUE_ID", "3", ....);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query_result)){
        $newRow = array();
        foreach($order as $value) {
            $newRow[$value] = $row[$value];
        }
        $result[]=$newRow;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This will actually loop row by row and order it in your desired column order.

On a side note:

Your code is pretty dangerous and vulnerable for SQL Injections. You shall never directly put the content of a variable inside a SQL query!

```
$user_id = "Somestring with spaces";
$last_sync = "2013-08-07 15:51:25";
$ary=mysql_query("SELECT tRelations.ID,tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID,tRelations.RECEIVER_ID,
    tRelations.IS_TEST,tRelations.STATE,tRelations.UNIQUE_ID,tRelations.LAST_MODIFIED,
    tRelations.CREATED FROM tRelations 
            JOIN tUserData ON (tUserData.UNIQUE_ID=tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID) 
            JOIN tUsers ON (tUsers.ID=tUserData.USER_ID) 
        WHERE tUsers.ID=$user_id AND tRelations.last_modified>'$last_sync' 
        ORDER BY tRelations.ID ASC;") or die(mysql_error());
```

This would result in a query of

```
SELECT tRelations.ID,tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID,tRelations.RECEIVER_ID,
    tRelations.IS_TEST,tRelations.STATE,tRelations.UNIQUE_ID,tRelations.LAST_MODIFIED,
    tRelations.CREATED FROM tRelations 
            JOIN tUserData ON (tUserData.UNIQUE_ID=tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID) 
            JOIN tUsers ON (tUsers.ID=tUserData.USER_ID) 
        WHERE tUsers.ID=Somestring with spaces AND tRelations.last_modified>'2013-08-07 15:51:25'
        ORDER BY tRelations.ID ASC;"
```

You see the flaw? That's because "$user_id" wasn't escaped. You should **always** use [mysqli_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) to escape your string. For example:

```
$ary=mysql_query("SELECT tRelations.ID,tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID,tRelations.RECEIVER_ID,
    tRelations.IS_TEST,tRelations.STATE,tRelations.UNIQUE_ID,tRelations.LAST_MODIFIED,
    tRelations.CREATED FROM tRelations 
            JOIN tUserData ON (tUserData.UNIQUE_ID=tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID) 
            JOIN tUsers ON (tUsers.ID=tUserData.USER_ID) 
        WHERE tUsers.ID=".mysqli_escape_string($user_id)." AND tRelations.last_modified>'".mysqli_escape_string($last_sync)."' 
        ORDER BY tRelations.ID ASC;") or die(mysql_error());
```

Or even better: Use PDO (PHP Data Objects) when interacting with database. PDO is supported since PHP 5.1 and allows safe interaction with the database. It requires a little bit more code, but significantly improves the readability and security of your PHP application.

Comment: I have already used escape_string on the input variables, so I don't think that this answers my question. But thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The order that the fields are appearing in the JSON object is not intentional, and is part of the problem. I want it to appear in the order that I have it in the query in my OP, i.e. beginning with ID, not State. I can't see why it isn't.

Comment: Usually you should have too worry about the order in JSON, since unlike XML for JSON there are no schemes. When converted to an object or array it's accessed by name not by order. But `json_encode` does it in the order in which the key value pairs were added. `$json["first"] = 1; $json["second"] = 2; json_encode($json);` results in `{ "first" : 1, "second" : 2 }`. It's probably the way mysql adds the fields to the column table internally when generating the row

Comment: Thanks for the next edit, that looks like it should work. I'll try it a bit later after some sleep and let you know how I get on. But just to clarify, I don't want it in the order that the JSON Object is currently outputting as, I want it in this order -- tRelations.ID,tRelations.DATA_RECORD_UUID,tRelations.RECEIVER_ID,tRelations.IS_TEST,tRelations.STATE,tRelations.UNIQUE_ID,tRelations.LAST_MODIFIED,tRelations.CREATED

Comment: Ah just saw your comment, okay then. Will let you know later how it's gone, thanks.